# How to split an variable procedure

Tags: vba, excel

So my code is simple but I don't know how to break it up in a simple way.

```
Dim o As Range  
Set o = Sheets("PalmFamily").Range(B1).End(xlDown).Select
```

So how can move ".Range(B1).End(xlDown).Select" down to the next line like so but still have it = o

```
Dim o As Range  
Set o = Sheets("PalmFamily").Select
Range(B1).End(xlDown).Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is a bit unclear but this is possible solution:

```
Sheets("PalmFamily").Activate
Dim o As Range  
Set o = Sheets("PalmFamily").Range(B1).End(xlDown)
o.Select
```

Comment: I guess I didn't explain my backstory to this well enough, my fault. So on line I'm trying to use it as a range for later coding like so.    Sheets("PalmFamily").Select
        Range(o).Slecet
        ActiveSheet.Paste

Comment: but line Set o = Sheets("PalmFamily").Range(B1).End(xlDown).Select                                                      Does not work so im thinking I would need to plit it up in order for it work right

Comment: so, you have it in my answer. You don't need to call it like `Range(o).select` but `o.select` is enough and correct.

Comment: also, forget the selects. If this is just for VBA and you dont need to show the user then just assign the range rather than using selections. It is substantially quicker. Set o = Sheets("PalmFamily").Cells(1,2).End(xlDown). No need for the Selects, or Sheet Activate etc.

Comment: @Cor_Blimey, you are right but check the question, OP wants to do both: move and keep `o variable` reference. If so, it's good to be sure that we are in correct sheet.

Comment: @KazJaw yeah my comment was to the OP - I should have @ him. I realise you are just refactoring the original code as requested :-). However, I imagine the OP doesn't actually need to select/activate but believes that is how it should be done (Macro Recorder bad habits coming through perhaps).